# Inappropriate ioctl for device on socket read

Tags: perl, sockets, ioctl, inet

```
    my $waitlist = IO::Select->new($self->{sock});
    while($datalen < 9)
    {
            ##timeout set as 50
            if($waitlist->can_read($timeout || 0)) {
                    print_message(LOGLEVEL_TRACE, "INSIDE IF....", LOG_TAG);
                    $templen = $self->{sock}->sysread($tempdata, 9 - $datalen);
            } else {
                    print_message(LOGLEVEL_TRACE, "INSIDE ELSE....", LOG_TAG);
                    print_message(LOGLEVEL_TRACE, "B4 ERROR $!", LOG_TAG);
                    $templen = 0;
                    $! = EWOULDBLOCK;
            }
           
            print_message(LOGLEVEL_TRACE, "ERROR $!", LOG_TAG);
    }
```

In the above code, "can_read" getting error out as Inappropriate ioctl for device. Like to know the reason and fix need to do.

Comment: Is `sock` properly initialized and does it refer to a socket in a valid state (open, no errors)?

Answer (score 3):

`$!` is only meaningful after a system call indicates it set `$!`.

Problems:

- You don't check if a system call set `$!` before using it.
- You call `print_message` between the system call in which you're interested and the use of `$!`, and `print_message` can surely make system calls.

One thing to note is the way of checking if `can_read` returned an error is really weird.

> Return an array of handles that are ready for reading. `TIMEOUT` is the maximum amount of time to wait before returning an empty list (with `$!` unchanged), in seconds, possibly fractional. If `TIMEOUT` is not given and any handles are registered then the call will block indefinitely. Upon error, an empty list is returned, with `$!` set to indicate the error. To distinguish between timeout and error, set `$!` to zero before calling this method, and check it after an empty list is returned.

---

Replace

```perl
my $waitlist = IO::Select->new($self->{sock});
while($datalen < 9)
{
     ##timeout set as 50
    if($waitlist->can_read($timeout || 0)) {
        print_message(LOGLEVEL_TRACE, "INSIDE IF....", LOG_TAG);
        $templen = $self->{sock}->sysread($tempdata, 9 - $datalen);
    } else {
        print_message(LOGLEVEL_TRACE, "INSIDE ELSE....", LOG_TAG);
        print_message(LOGLEVEL_TRACE, "B4 ERROR $!", LOG_TAG);
        $templen = 0;
        $! = EWOULDBLOCK;
    }
       
    print_message(LOGLEVEL_TRACE, "ERROR $!", LOG_TAG);
}
```

with

```perl
my $waitlist = IO::Select->new($self->{sock});
while (length($tempdata) < 9) {
    $! = 0;
    my @handles = $waitlist->can_read($timeout || 0);
    if ($!) { # Yuck, just about anywhere else, this would be wrong.
        print_message(LOGLEVEL_TRACE, "SELECT FAILED: $!", LOG_TAG);
        ...abort...
    }

    if (!@handles) {
        print_message(LOGLEVEL_TRACE, "SELECT FAILED: Timeout", LOG_TAG);
        ...abort...
    }

    my $bytes_read = $self->{sock}->sysread($tempdata, 9 - $datalen, length($tempdata));
    if (!defined($bytes_read)) {
        print_message(LOGLEVEL_TRACE, "SYSREAD FAILED: $!", LOG_TAG);
        ...abort...
    }

    if (!$bytes_read) {
        if (length($tempdata)) {
           print_message(LOGLEVEL_TRACE, "SYSREAD FAILED: Premature EOF", LOG_TAG);
           ...abort...
        }

        # Reached EOF without reading anything.
        last;
    }
}
```

Until you perform these changes, we don't know if you got an error, much less what it is.

---

Comments:

- You were missing the final argument for `sysread`, which is necessary here.
- Using `select` as you did above is totally useless if there's no timeout (because there's only one handle). `sysread` will already perform the necessary waiting.
- If there is a timeout, it's not an absolute timeout. For example, say you have a timeout of 5 seconds, but you consistently get 1 byte every 4 seconds, the above will run for 36 seconds without timing out. (Ok, that's not a realistic example, but only because we're only reading 9 bytes.) For an absolute timeout, you'll need to keep track of how time has already gone by. (I'd use `my $wait_til = time() + timeout();` up front, and pass `$wait_til - time()` to `can_read`, after checking if it's positive or not.)

Comment: hi appreciate your support. I have modified my code as you suggested above. I have noticed 2 things 
1. Even after setting $!=0, it is always returning as ‘Inappropriate ioctl for device’. But this is not causing issue. I could see for both success and failure transfer this error message is coming. 
2. The issue what i think causing is after adding this below lines I can see ‘SELECT FAILED: Timeout’ message comes on the transfer failure cases. Whereas it not occurs for success transfer files. So hope this time out is causing issue. Can you please suggest what I need to do.

Comment: It's very common for Perl system calls to set `$!` to that value when there is no error. As soon as I saw `Inappropriate ioctl for device` (which is `ENOTTY`), I knew you were using `$!` without checking if the last system call indicated an error. Now you say you do this and still getting the error, so you're saying there's a bug in Perl. And frankly, I don't believe you. `ENOTTY` isn't even an error that `select` can return in Linux.

Comment: Like to know your comment on point 2. The issue what i think causing is after adding this below lines I can see ‘SELECT FAILED: Timeout’ message comes on the transfer failure cases. Where as it not occurs in success jobs. 
So hope this time out is causing issue. Can you please suggest what I need to do. 
  $! = 0;
    my @handles = $waitlist->can_read($timeout || 0);

  if ($!) { # Yuck, just about anywhere
        print_message(LOGLEVEL_TRACE, "SELECT FAILED: $!", LOG_TAG);
    }

    if (!@handles) {
        print_message(LOGLEVEL_TRACE, "SELECT FAILED: Timeout", LOG_TAG)
    }

Comment: You didn't abort. You kept right on going... You need a `die` or `return` or `exit` in there.

Comment: If i add die (abort) the transfers getting stopped. I need to know why timeout is coming ? Is that something in server settings i need to check or upgrade ? My expected result is need to overcome that time out issue and transfer the files. So any chances the server settings or server configurations or network issues causing this which we need to check ?

Comment: There's is no timeout. Your are printing that message even what there is no timeout. You modified my code so that it makes no sense at all. Any messages you get from it are meaningless because you removed the aborts.